# Create customer using magento Soap API

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, soap-api-v2

I am trying to create new customer using magento soap api , here is my code :

```
    $client = new SoapClient('http://map.itgprojects.pw/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');


    `$session = $client->login('mylogiin',` 'myapikey');
    $result = $client->customerCustomerCreate($session, ['email' => 'cusdtomedr-mail@example.org', 'firstname' => 'Dough', 'lastname' => 'Deeks', 'password' => 'password', 'website_id' => 1, 'store_id' => 1, 'group_id' => 1]);

    var_dump ($result);
```

I keep getting this error and I don't know why, even if the user has been added to the database :

> Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] Call to a member
>   function getUserId() on null in
>   /home/mapitgprojects/public_html/api/customer.php:51

version of `magento : 1.9`

I am working on an ionic app and I'am creating a web service to do some stuff.

Thank you for your help

[image]

Comment: Please try the code which is in answer.

Comment: I'm using SOAP V2, but I tried your answer it didn't work , I'm having the same error : Call to a member function getUserId() on null

Comment: Hi, please check updated answer

Comment: Is it your first soap api ?

Comment: yes it is my first, I 'm having the same error with ur updated answer. I can retrieve list of customers with customerCustomerList but i can't add a new one

Comment: Okay, no worries.

Comment: Can you please share the screen ?

Comment: you're welcome bro :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83801/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-hanane-kacemi).

Answer (score 1):

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');

// If some stuff requires api authentication,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$result = $client->customerCustomerCreate($session, array('email' => 'customer-mail@example.org', 'firstname' => 'Dough', 'lastname' => 'Deeks', 'password' => 'password', 'website_id' => 1, 'store_id' => 1, 'group_id' => 1));

var_dump ($result);
```

**Request Example SOAP V1**

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');

// If somestuff requires api authentication,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$result = $client->call($session,'customer.create',array(array('email' => 'mail@example.org', 'firstname' => 'Dough', 'lastname' => 'Deeks', 'password' => 'password', 'website_id' => 1, 'store_id' => 1, 'group_id' => 1)));

var_dump ($result);

// If you don't need the session anymore
//$client->endSession($session);
```